# White space at right of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My page has a white space on the right side when using margins and padding in the mobile view.

My page:

https://www.blazor.nl/uploads/get/a83c2617117c88b0/IMG-0002

My CSS:

```
.page-wrapper .page-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative; }
    .page-wrapper .page-container .content-wrapper {
     margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
      min-height: 600px;
      position: relative;
      top: -120px; }
      .page-wrapper .page-container .content-wrapper .maincontent {
        padding: 30px; } }
      @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
        .page-wrapper .page-container .content-wrapper .maincontent {
          padding: 20px; } }

.page-wrapper .page-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative; }
  .page-wrapper .page-container .content-wrapper > h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-weight: 300; }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .page-wrapper .page-container .content-wrapper > h2 {
        color: #696969;
        font-size: 24px; } }
  @media (max-width: 992px) {
    .page-wrapper .page-container .content-wrapper {
      margin: 30px 30px 0 150px; } }
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .page-wrapper .page-container .content-wrapper {
      margin: 15px; } }
```

I am using a snippet which can be found here: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/dexRM.  I also use Bootstrap 3.

Thanks

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Well, I want to remove that white space...

Comment: That image does not have any unwanted space

Comment: It does, I have added the link to the image to see it better

Comment: Somehow it solves itself when I added the layout into my CakePHP app. Must be something with HTML

Comment: Please add HTML code also